# How can I write my name Nicole in Japanese?

Tags: names

How can I write my name
Nicole in Japanese?

Comment: ニコール is probably the closest transliteration.

Answer (score 3):

I think [ニコル](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%8B%E3%82%B3%E3%83%AB) would be the most common. There are variants like ニコール, ニコラ.

Eg

- [藤田ニコル](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%97%A4%E7%94%B0%E3%83%8B%E3%82%B3%E3%83%AB) (Fujita Nicole)
- Jung Nicole - [チョン・ニコル](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%81%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%E3%83%BB%E3%83%8B%E3%82%B3%E3%83%AB)
- Clive William Nicol - [C. W. ニコル](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%E3%83%BBW%E3%83%BB%E3%83%8B%E3%82%B3%E3%83%AB)
- Nicole Kidman - [ニコール・キッドマン](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%8B%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%83%BB%E3%82%AD%E3%83%83%E3%83%89%E3%83%9E%E3%83%B3)

Answer (score 1):

That's kind of up to you.  Though you could play with the pronunciation of your name and go with Niko.  It would sound like you're a fun and happy person; ニコニコ
(*nikoniko*) is an of onomatopoeic word in Japanese which gives that feeling.

But if you want Kanji, then that's really your personal preference and there aren't really any rules about it.

Comment: However, I've heard a few times that writing one's own name in Kanji as a foreigner is considered a faux pass, so perhaps be a little careful with that.

Comment: Wouldn't it be appropriate to at least offer common spellings of Nicole in katakana?

Comment: @Sam  Interesting point.  When I was in Japan, I received quite a number of suggestions for Kanji.  Perhaps that's because in Japanese, the first two syllables (four mora) of my first name sound like a common family name and the remaining syllable (two mora) sounds like a reasonable first name.   But then there was the problem that I just had a real last name that just doesn't match at all.  lol

Comment: @Leebo I suppose, but it looks like someone already made such a comment. I just thought I'd go for an outside the box answer, something someone new to Japanese might not consider as a possibility.

Comment: If I was new to Japanese and the answer didn't say you can write it in katakana, that would make me think maybe you can't. (shrug)

Comment: @Leebo Excellent point.  I hadn't thought of it that way.  Good for me to keep in mind.